# Hierarchical data from 3 tables according to the role type

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Following are my tables:

**[UserMaster]**

UserId Int, UserName Varchar(200),AddedBy Int

```
UserId     EmpName           AddedBy
1          admin             0
2          SubAdmin1         1
3          Vikas             2
4          Mohit             3
5          Atul              4
6          Vishal            2
7          Mani              3
8          Sunny             1
```

**[SalesMaster]**

SalesId Int, UserId Int (FK_UserMaster_UserId) , Price Int

```
SalesId  UserId    Price         StatusId
10        1        100         1 
11        2        200         1    
12        3        300         1
13        4        500         1
14        5        100             2
15        6        200             1
16        7        111             2
17        8        222             1
```

[SalesProducts]

SaleProductId Int, SaleId Int (FK_SaleMaster_SaleId) , Quantity Int

```
SaleProductId    SalesId   Quantity

  1                10       2
  2                11       2
  3                12       1
  4                13       1
  5                14       3
  6                15       2
  7                16       5
  8                17       1
```

[output]

The result set should have the sales of the login user + the users created by him and the further users created by the thier sub users.

The following TotalSalesAmount is:

[SalesMaster].Price * [SalesProducts].Quantity

For eg: Total Sales amount for UserId: 1 is 
100*2+200*2+ 300*1 + 500*1 +100*3 + 200*2 +111*5 + 222*1= 2877

Similarly for UserId: 2 is 
200*2+300*1 + 200*2 +500*1 + 111*5 +200*2= 2555

case 1:

In case (admin)UserId=1 will login , We need to show following

```
UserId     TotalSalesAmount    OwnSaleAmount           AddedBy

  1          2877         200               0

  2          2555         400               1

  3          1355             300               2

  4          800          500           3

  5          100*3= 300       300           4

  6          200*2=200        200           2

  7          111*5= 555       555               3

  8          222*1= 222       222           1
```

Case 2: 
In case (Vikas)UserId=3 will login , We need to show following

```
 UserId      TotalSalesAmount           OwnSaleAmount           AddedBy

  3          300*1 + 500*1 + 111*5= 1355            300                2

  4          500*1 + 100*3= 800                     500                3

  5          100*3= 300                         300            4

  7          111*5= 555                     555                3
```

The table script and data is here which i have used 
**http://test-admin.teamberry.biz/SalesScript.rar**  ,

After running this script please execute below query take UM.UserId=164, SM.statusID = 1
The TotalSalesAmount for UserId=166 is coming wrong as its TotalSaleAmount should be same as ownSaleAmount i.e 444 because UserId=166 don't have any child.

```
with tblOwnSaleAmount as 
 ( 
      select UM.UserId,UM.EmpName,UM.AddedBy,cast(sum( SM.Price*SP.Quantity) as int) as OwnSaleAmount 
      from UserMaster UM
      left join SalesMaster SM on SM.UserId = UM.UserId  and SM.statusID = 1
      left join SalesProducts SP on SP.SalesId = SM.SalesId
      where UM.UserId = 164
      group by  UM.UserId ,UM.AddedBy,UM.EmpName 
      union all 
      select UM.UserId,UM.EmpName, UM.AddedBy, 
      case when SM.statusID = 1 then cast(( SM.Price*SP.Quantity ) as int)
      else 0 end as OwnSaleAmount
      from UserMaster UM
      join tblOwnSaleAmount on tblOwnSaleAmount.UserId = UM.AddedBy
      join SalesMaster SM on SM.UserId = UM.UserId 
      join SalesProducts SP on SP.SalesId = SM.SalesId 
 )
,  tbldistinctOwnSaleAmount as
 (
 select distinct UserId,EmpName, AddedBy,Isnull(OwnSaleAmount,0) as  OwnSaleAmount
 from tblOwnSaleAmount
 )
 ,

 tblTotalOwnSaleAmount as
 (
  select OSA.UserId,OSA.EmpName, OSA.AddedBy, sum( OSA.OwnSaleAmount ) as OwnSaleAmount
  from tbldistinctOwnSaleAmount OSA --inner join tbldistinctOwnSaleAmount A on OSA.AddedBy = A.UserID
  group by OSA.UserId ,OSA.AddedBy,OSA.EmpName
 )
 select OSA.* 
, TotalSalesAmount = isnull(
( 
    select sum( OSA1.OwnSaleAmount )
    from tblTotalOwnSaleAmount OSA1
    where OSA1.UserId > OSA.UserId 
), 0 )
+ OSA.OwnSaleAmount
 from tblTotalOwnSaleAmount OSA  
 order by OSA.UserId
```

Answer (score 1):

Please update if my understanding is wrong :

1. For userID 3 you have taken TotalSalesAmount = 300*1 + 500*1 + 111*5 ( not included SaleAmount for userID 5 which in turn has been created by userID 4 sub user for userid 3) . So TotalSalesAmount 
   for userID 3 should be calculated as: 300*1 + 500*1 +300*1 + 111*5 = 1655 and not 1355.

If my above understanding is correct you can get the desired result by using recursive capability of common table expression and then calculate the running total as:

`-- create a common table expression to get OwnSaleAmount for logged in user and all the users who are added` by current user and further .

```
 with tblOwnSaleAmount as 
 ( 
      select UM.UserId, UM.AddedBy, ( SM.Price*SP.Quantity ) as OwnSaleAmount 
      from UserMaster UM
      join SalesMaster SM on SM.UserId = UM.UserId 
      join SalesProducts SP on SP.SaleId = SM.SalesId 
      where UM.UserId = 1 -- Userid of logged in user which will act as anchor member 
                          -- for later subqueries
      union all 

      select UM.UserId, UM.AddedBy, ( SM.Price*SP.Quantity ) as OwnSaleAmount  
      from UserMaster UM
      join tblOwnSaleAmount on tblOwnSaleAmount.UserId = UM.AddedBy
      join SalesMaster SM on SM.UserId = UM.UserId 
      join SalesProducts SP on SP.SaleId = SM.SalesId 

 )
 select OSA.* 
, TotalSalesAmount = isnull(
( 
    select sum( OSA1.OwnSaleAmount )
    from tblOwnSaleAmount OSA1
    where OSA1.AddedBy > = OSA.UserId                                                                   
), 0 )
+ OSA.OwnSaleAmount
 from tblOwnSaleAmount OSA
 order by OSA.UserId
```

EDIT: Updated query:

```
 --1. Corrected joins in anchor query to fetch records for users who have no records in SalesMaster Table.
 --2. IS it another requirement that user entries with status id = 2 should not be considered?
 with tblOwnSaleAmount as 
 ( 
      select UM.UserId, UM.AddedBy, sum( SM.Price*SP.Quantity ) as OwnSaleAmount 
      from UserMaster UM
      left join SalesMaster SM on SM.UserId = UM.UserId -- Missed requirement1
      left join SalesProducts SP on SP.SaleId = SM.SalesId -- Missed requirement1
      where UM.UserId = 2 -- Userid of logged in user which will act as anchor member 
      group by  UM.UserId ,UM.AddedBy                  -- for later subqueries

      union all 

      select UM.UserId, UM.AddedBy, ( SM.Price*SP.Quantity ) as OwnSaleAmount  
      from UserMaster UM
      join tblOwnSaleAmount on tblOwnSaleAmount.UserId = UM.AddedBy
      join SalesMaster SM on SM.UserId = UM.UserId 
      join SalesProducts SP on SP.SaleId = SM.SalesId 

 ),
  tbldistinctOwnSaleAmount as
 (
 select distinct UserId, AddedBy, OwnSaleAmount 
 from tblOwnSaleAmount
 ) ,
 tblTotalOwnSaleAmount as
 (
  select OSA.UserId,OSA.AddedBy, sum( OSA.OwnSaleAmount ) as OwnSaleAmount
  from tbldistinctOwnSaleAmount OSA
  group by OSA.UserId ,OSA.AddedBy
 )
 select OSA.* 
, TotalSalesAmount = isnull(
( 
    select sum( OSA1.OwnSaleAmount )
    from tblTotalOwnSaleAmount OSA1
    where OSA1.UserId > OSA.UserId                                                                   
), 0 )
+ OSA.OwnSaleAmount
 from tblTotalOwnSaleAmount OSA
 order by OSA.UserId
```

Hope this helps!!!

[EDIT2]: Updated query for missed requirement 2:

```
 --2. IS it another requirement that user entries with status id = 2 should not be considered? -- Yes!!!
 with tblOwnSaleAmount as 
 ( 
      select UM.UserId, UM.AddedBy, sum( SM.Price*SP.Quantity ) as OwnSaleAmount 
      from UserMaster UM
      left join SalesMaster SM on SM.UserId = UM.UserId  and SM.statusID = 1-- Missed requirement1 and 2
      left join SalesProducts SP on SP.SaleId = SM.SalesId -- Missed requirement1
      where UM.UserId = 2 -- Userid of logged in user which will act as anchor member 
      group by  UM.UserId ,UM.AddedBy                  -- for later subqueries

      union all 

      select UM.UserId, UM.AddedBy, 
      case when SM.statusID = 1 then ( SM.Price*SP.Quantity ) 
      else 0 end as OwnSaleAmount  --Missed Requirement 2.
      from UserMaster UM
      join tblOwnSaleAmount on tblOwnSaleAmount.UserId = UM.AddedBy
      join SalesMaster SM on SM.UserId = UM.UserId 
      join SalesProducts SP on SP.SaleId = SM.SalesId 

 ),
  tbldistinctOwnSaleAmount as
 (
 select distinct UserId, AddedBy, OwnSaleAmount 
 from tblOwnSaleAmount
 ) ,
 tblTotalOwnSaleAmount as
 (
  select OSA.UserId,OSA.AddedBy, sum( OSA.OwnSaleAmount ) as OwnSaleAmount
  from tbldistinctOwnSaleAmount OSA
  group by OSA.UserId ,OSA.AddedBy
 )
 select OSA.* 
, TotalSalesAmount = isnull(
( 
    select sum( OSA1.OwnSaleAmount )
    from tblTotalOwnSaleAmount OSA1
    where OSA1.UserId > OSA.UserId                                                                   
), 0 )
+ OSA.OwnSaleAmount
 from tblTotalOwnSaleAmount OSA
 order by OSA.UserId
```

*To get correct results you need to update the on predicate of anchor table and then add case statement for further recursive tables.*

Comment: Thanks for your valuable feedback. It worked for me except i did a little change in the query, I have changed Addedby to UserId   select OSA.* 
, TotalSalesAmount = isnull(
( 
    select sum( OSA1.OwnSaleAmount )
    from tblOwnSaleAmount OSA1
    where OSA1.UserId > = OSA.UserId  --ctm                                                                   
), 0 )

Comment: Please review...  If logged in user has no records in SalesMaster table, then the query is returning zero results. Also, if the SalesMaster table has multiple entries for same UserID then also the results are incorrect.                                           Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi..just saw your updated requirements. you still looking out for answer?

Comment: Well, I must say "Hats-Off" to your SQL skills. Yes, I am still looking for the query. Can you please answer       http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/19362433/2

Comment: Updated query as per your requirements. Is it another requirement that user entries with status id = 2 should not be considered?

Comment: Yes, its the parameter we can either pass StatusId=1 Or StatusId=2

Comment: I want to have a check of StatusId too..I have tried with the left join in CTE but recursive part didnt take outer joins..Can you please modify the query with the condition of "Where StatusId=@StatusId" , As if the user dont have record in SalesMaster table for StatusId=@StatusId, Then the ownSaleAmount will be Zero for that user but the total salesAmount may come depending on their sub users if they have record of that @StatusId in SalesMaster. The more detailed explanation i have given on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19362433/recursive-sql-query-to-get-amount-according-to-the-role

Comment: To get correct results you need to update the on predicate of anchor table and then add case statement for further recursive tables. Hope now it's solved :)

Comment: Actually the query is somewhat right but it gives wrong results at second level, The easy way to debug this query is start from lower level, find the result for userID at the lowest level and note the result, now decrease the userId level one by one and note the result for each user id's TotalSaleAmount, When you reach the top level then the result(TotalSaleAmount) which you have noted before is different at the top most level, Means If we take UserId=1 then result(TotalSaleAmount) for  UserId=4 should be the same in the case when we pass UserId=4. Are you getting my point ?

Comment: I found the bug but not the answer yet,The problem is in last statememt of calculating the TotalSalesAmount, ** "select OSA.* 
, TotalSalesAmount = isnull(
( 
    select sum( OSA1.OwnSaleAmount )
    from tblTotalOwnSaleAmount OSA1
    where OSA1.UserId > OSA.UserId    
), 0 )
+ OSA.OwnSaleAmount
 from tblTotalOwnSaleAmount OSA"**   . It sums up all the Users ownSaleAmount   where OSA1.UserId > OSA.UserId. As in between some users dont have their child.

Comment: Can you please post what exactly are the results that you want to show in above case so that i can analyze where exactly is the miss..

Comment: Are you able to track my problem now ?